# Local variable 'value' referenced before assignment: qgis function editor

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-custom-function

I customized a function to edit my attribute table. It was working well but now when I used it again my QGIS crash or I receive a bad answer.

The answer of QGIS:
[image]

My code:

```
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def change_name_field(field, feature, parent):
    if 'agropecuaria' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Agroforestry'
    elif 'agua' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Water'
    elif 'cabruca' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Agroforestry'
    elif 'capoeira' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Secondary Forest'
    elif 'eucalipto2limao' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Silviculture'
    elif 'eucalipto3limao' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Silviculture'
    elif 'eucalipto2mad' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Silviculture'
    elif 'eucalipto4madesc' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Silviculture'
    elif 'mangue' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Mangrove'
    elif 'mata' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Forest'
    elif 'nuvem' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Cloud'
    elif 'solo arenoso' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Sand Soil'
    elif 'solo exposto' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Bare Soil'
    elif 'solo umido' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Soil Moist'
    elif 'sombra' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Shadow'
    elif 'Agroforestry' in str(field):
        value1 = 'Shadow'
    return value1
```

Comment: make value1 = 'Not found' on the first line of your function.. I'd suggest your problem is none of your strings are found in your field, in this case the function will return 'Not found' instead of None.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did what you said me. But it only worked well when I checked virtual field. I waited that cells that my functions didn't have value to return string value was recorded with "Not found", houwever Null value was returned. So, it wasn't work how we thought but help me to see values that my function didn't have.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Qgis was crashed when I click on Load bottom, every time. Sometime, the Custom options didn't appear. I don't know why but it was a little difficult to do it. I installed it again but this behavior continue.

Comment: Apologies but I'm not sure what it is exactly you are trying to do. Are you wanting to change the names of fields or populate a field with values?

Comment: I want to populate field with values. I have a field that I would liketo use as reference to populate another one. I have to do it, because when i did classification I set class names of land use in portuguese, my native language. So, I create a function to take logic that change values from portuguese to english in a new field. In my post, I am creating a new field called "name_class". The referente field taht I used to populate an another is "Class_Name".

Comment: Ahhh. It worked well.

Comment: Now I think have had qgis bug. I have tried to do other custom function an another file and I realized same behavior problem. I reported it.
https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15242